# How can a templatize subchart values?

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

For context I have an application, and it depends on the `mysql` chart. I've set up the [mysql stable](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mysql) chart as a dependent chart in `myapp` chart.

I have a very large set of sql files, and due to their size, I need to pack them into a specialized seed container. Using the standard helm chart, I can pass in a seed container to init my database as shown in the below `values.yaml` snippet.

Are there any strategies to get subchart values created at runtime into my `values.yaml`?

```
mysql:
  extraInitContainers: |
    - name: init-seed
      image: foobar/seed:0.1.0
      env: 
      - name: MYSQL_HOSTNAME
        value: foobar-mysql
      - name: MYSQL_USER
        value: foo
      - name: MYSQL_PASS
        value: bar
```

I've tried ways to do the below, but to no avail.

a. Templatize and pass a service name into the `MYSQL_HOSTNAME` env var

b. Pass the `{{ include "mangos_zero.fullname" . }}` helper into this value

c. Find the name of the other container within the `mysql` pod at runtime?

How can I get the service name of the `mysql-chart` or it's container name passed into my init pod?

Answer (score 1):

Not into your `values.yaml` but yes into your templates. Assuming you are using Helm v3 you can use the [lookup function](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/functions_and_pipelines/#using-the-lookup-function). For example, wherever you need the service name from your MySQL DB to create your seed data.

```yaml
(lookup "v1" "Service" "mynamespace" "mysql-chart").metadata.name
```